# jQuery change css print onclick: firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, printing

I have a problem with firefox, declaring the style sheet printing

```
<link id="printstyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
      media="print" href="css/print.css" />
```

and adding this little jquery

```
$('#con').click(function(){
 $('#printstyle').attr('href', 'css/print.css');
 window.print();
});

$('#senza').click(function(){
 $('#printstyle').attr('href', 'css/print2.css');
 window.print();
});
```

I can choose the style sheet for printing

ok in all browsers except Firefox, where is the problem?

Comment: Try this `$('#con').click(function(){
 $('#printstyle').prop('href', 'css/print.css');
 window.print();
});`

$('#senza').click(function(){
 $('#printstyle').prop('href', 'css/print2.css');
 window.print();
});

Comment: thanks, I made the changes you said, but I get the same result, firefox does not take the css selected